# Topic limit exceeded when updating PushTopic

Tags: apex, force.com, streaming-api

I can create and update PushTopics without issue until the limit is reached. Once the limit is reached, I can't update existing topics, the following error is thrown:

> Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id xxx; first error:
>   LIMIT_EXCEEDED, exceeded the maximum allowed number of push topics: []

[note - xxx == Id of the PushTopic]

I am not inserting or upserting - just updating the query on a single topic.

If the org limit is 20 topics, everything works perfectly up until 19 topics. At 20 topics this error is thrown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears as bug to me.

What i would do as workaround is check how many topics are already there and stop creating any push topic after 19.

Comment: In fact this is what we have done for the time being. We store the maximum topics available (n) in a custom setting and limit to n-1.